# Solr number of fields in a document

Tags: search, solr

Is there a constraint on the number of fields returned for a document in search results? I am facing an issue wherein only some fields are getting returned while others are not (though the query does return a result). Please let me know if someone has come across a similar issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many fields do you have? are all fields stored? if not, only the stored fields will be returned.

Comment: You need to put more effort into your questions. Please provide your configuration, your query, your expected result, and your actual result.

Comment: Hi Kromit. Also i have around 40 to 45 fields and all are stored fields. In my response i am getting around 20 fields.

Comment: @beerbajay. I am using DIH to fetch records from my Oracle DB. In my schema i have around 50 stored fields and 2 indexed fields. When i perform a search through the solr admin page i see only few fields(around 20) being returned.

Comment: are you sure all fields are **!=null**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify the **fl** parameter in your query to define the fields you want.

the default value ***,score** should return all **stored** fields.

the fields with **null** values will also not be returned.

Comment: Hi Kromit. I tried with fl = * explicitely as well.. Still some fields are missing..

Comment: Are they stored in your schema.xml ?

Comment: Thanks Kromit. On recheck found the fields which were missing were null.. Thanks again. Missed it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Constraint from Solr for the Number of fields to be returned.
All the fields marked stored should be returned with `fl=*`.
But, the field should hold some value to be returned by Solr. If the field does not hold any value that field will not be returned as a part of the response.
So the fields returned for the documents would vary depending upon whether they hold any value or not.